# C++ getline errors using char arrays

Tags: c++

I keep getting an error saying "  error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, char [100])'|  "  on getline(Input, sentence). I might be missing something, Im not sure. What I'm trying to do is read an entire line from the input and insert it into char sentence[100] using getline. I have to use getline per the requirements for the assignment. Thank you in advance.

```
char uniqueWords[100][16] = {""};
int multipleWords = 0;
int theWords[100];
int totalWords = 0;
char sentence[100];
char delimit[] = " /.";


ifstream Input;
Input.open("input.txt");
if (!Input.is_open())
{
    cout << "Error Opening File";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

ofstream Output;
Output.open("output.txt", std::ios_base::app);
if (!Output.is_open())
{
    cout << "Error Opening File";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


char *p;

while(!Input.eof())
{
    getline(Input, sentence);
    p = strtok(sentence, delimit);
    while(p)
    {
        Output << p ;
        words(p, uniqueWords, theWords, multipleWords);   // a function for the assignment
        totalWords++;
        p = strtok(nullptr,delimit);
    }
    create << "." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Of course. `getline (stream, std::string)` takes `std::string` as the argument. You want `stream.getline (char array, size)` (e.g. `Input.getline (sentence, sizeof sentence)`)  Why are you using character arrays instead of `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>>` for your storage?? See also [Why !.eof() inside a loop condition is always wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/9254539)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are attempting to use [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of [std::basic_istream::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). (e.g. you are using the wrong `getline()`) The `getline()` you are attempting to use expects a `std::string` for destination storage, not a plain old character array. The second form above happily takes a character array and its size for destination storage. You can use:

```
    while (Input.getline(sentence, sizeof sentence))
    {
        p = strtok (sentence, delimit);
        while (p)
        {
            Output << p ;
            words (p, uniqueWords, theWords, multipleWords);   // a function for the assignment
            totalWords++;
            p = strtok(nullptr,delimit);
        }
        std::cout << ".\n";
    }
```

Other thoughts, have a look at [Why !.eof() inside a loop condition is always wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/9254539). Note, control your read-loop with the stream-state which is available as a return from your input function. Also see [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696).

When you output an error message, use `std::cerr` to write to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. For example:

```
    std::ifstream Input ("input.txt");
    if (!Input.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error Opening File.\n";
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Other than that, you should really use `std::string` for your string storage and `std::vector<std::string>` for storage of a collection of strings. You can copy each string to a character array for parsing with `strtok()`. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.